# Location of has_capability() method in Moodle

Tags: moodle

I am trying to understand the access control in the Moodle. I want to have a look at the definition of the method `has_capability()` in the project. Anyone has any idea in which file can I find the definition of this method?

Comment: What. Is. A. Moodle? (o_O)

Comment: Moodle is a Course Management System (CMS), also known as a Learning Management System (LMS) or a Virtual Learning Environment (VLE). It is a Free web application that educators can use to create effective online learning sites.
For more information, check [moodle.org](http://moodle.org)

Comment: @ananthonline http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ftQ6A3DKKeg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you said, it's in the file called `accesslib.php` under `Server -> Moodle -> lib`.

Adding a little more info to that, `has_capability()` is one of the most important function of the moodle and it checks whether a user has a particular capability in a given context.

```
function has_capability($capability, context $context, $user = null, $doanything = true)
```

More info on this can be found [here](http://docs.moodle.org/dev/Access_API#has_capability.28.29).

Answer (score 2):

Finally found it!
If you download the moodle project, it's under the directory Server -> Moodle -> lib
And in that directory, it's defined in a file named 'accesslib.php'.